# jQuery only works after browser refresh on local Rails project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have both of these jQuery functions, which work fine if I refresh the browser window... But if I simply click through the site, jQuery below does not execute. I am not getting any console errors. I have tried wrapping it in both `$(window).on('load', function() { ... }` and `$(function(){ ... }`. I have also tried wrapping each individually like so: `$( ".accordion" ).on('load', function() { ... }`.

Any ideas would be at all appreciated since this is my first project in the Rails ecosystem.

```
// grow hover for landing page 
$(window).bind("resize",function(){
    console.log($(this).width());
    if($(this).width() <1024){
        $('div.causeBox').addClass('grow')
    }
    else{
        $('div.causeBox').removeClass('grow')
    }
})

// accordion animation
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

Is this an issue with my jQuery? Is this something strange about my local environment that I haven't run into before? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you using [turbo links](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks)? I believe it's enabled by default, but been a while since I started a fresh project

Comment: @SimpleLime I'm not sure because I'm the front-end dev on the project so that Rails project itself was started by the back-end dev. Is there an easy way for me to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible your project is using [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks), you can check this by looking for `turbolinks` in the **Gemfile** or checking **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** for `//= require turbolinks`. What Turbolinks does is:

> When you follow a link, Turbolinks automatically fetches the page, swaps in its `<body>`, and merges its `<head>`, all without incurring the cost of a full page load.

and because of this, you only ever actually load the page once, and then Turbolinks takes over and pseudo loads the pages from then on. In the [Running JavaScript When a Page Loads](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads) section of their README:

> You may be used to installing JavaScript behavior in response to the `window.onload`, `DOMContentLoaded`, or jQuery `ready` events. With Turbolinks, these events will fire only in response to the initial page load—not after any subsequent page changes.
>
> In many cases, you can simply adjust your code to listen for the `turbolinks:load` event, which fires once on the initial page load and again after every Turbolinks visit.
>
> ```
> document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
>   // ...
> })
> ```

You can read more about it in that [README](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks)

Comment: THANK YOU, @SimpleLime! That was the issue. As you suggested, `//= require turbolinks` was right there in the application.js file -- and adding that event lister worked perfectly. I really appreciate it.